# Prevent an absolutely positioned div from increasing the size of it's parent

Tags: html, css, background

I have a div filled with content, and I want to **stack background images behind it**. I **do not want to combine these background images,** because I am getting a long "largest contentful paint" on Google PageSpeed and have discovered that stacking smaller images gives me a better score on this metric. The **page must scroll** to the bottom of the content, but I want the **background images to be cut short** when the content ends.

---

The code below almost does what I want but does not cut the background images shorter.

```css
img {
 opacity: 0.3;
 z-index: -999;
}

.abs {
  position: absolute;
}

footer {
  background-color: rgba(238,130,238, 1);
}

.overflow{
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<div class='overflow'>
  <div class='abs'>
    <img src='https://sitesent.com/static/6d91c86c0fde632ba4cd01062fd9ccfa/5a190/gatsby-astronaut.png' />
    <img src='https://sitesent.com/static/6d91c86c0fde632ba4cd01062fd9ccfa/5a190/gatsby-astronaut.png' />
  </div>
  <h1>Hi people</h1>
  <p>This page should be able to scroll.</p>
  <div class='filler'>
    <p>filler</p><p>filler</p><p>filler</p><p>filler</p><p>filler</p>
    <p>filler</p><p>filler</p><p>filler</p><p>filler</p><p>filler</p><p>filler</p><p>filler</p><p>filler</p><p>filler</p><p>filler</p><p>filler</p><p>filler</p><p>filler</p>
    <p>filler</p><p>filler</p><p>filler</p><p>filler</p><p>filler</p><p>filler</p><p>filler</p><p>filler</p>
  </div>
  <footer>
    But the bottom of the page should be right below this line. The background images should not shrink, but should be cut off at this point
  </footer>
</div>
```

---

My project is with `gatsby`, so I [created a sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/stacking-absolutely-positioned-images-sam-t5sjt) for this problem using gatsby, but I was having some problems with the sandbox, so I don't think it works completely

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add:

```
position: relative;
```

to element with class:

```
overflow
```

**Updated demo:**
[Updated jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/gj5Lxk47/)